# OSX Server: apache2 running but “Problem loading page”

Tags: macos, apache2, osx-server

I have setup OSX Server 10.6, all updates installed, started apache2, which is running:

```
sudo apachectl graceful
```

I see in /var/log/apache2/errorlog

```
[Fri Dec 17 10:11:49 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Also

```
ps -ef | grep httpd
```

shows several processes:

```
    0 49388     1   0   0:00.05 ??         0:00.07 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
   70 49389 49388   0   0:00.00 ??         0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
   70 49390 49388   0   0:00.00 ??         0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
   70 49391 49388   0   0:00.00 ??         0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
   70 49392 49388   0   0:00.00 ??         0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
...
```

In httpd.conf I edited DocumentRoot:

```
ServerName bioinfo.mni.fh-giessen.de:80 
DocumentRoot "/Volumes/ServerHD2/Web_Documents"   
ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/error_log" 
<Directory "/Volumes/ServerHD2/Web_Documents">     
   Order Allow,Deny  
   Allow from All 
</Directory>
```

Syntax is OK:

```
apachectl configtest
Syntax OK
```

Yet, I get timeouts at http://bioinfo.mni.fh-giessen.de :

```
Problem loading page
```

Any clue ?

Comment: You should get error log entries for each failed request. Are you sure there are none? Is the server actually reachable under that IP?

Comment: No failed requests entries in /var/log/apache2/error_log or /var/log/apache2/access_log. I can login by ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you edited the right file?  OS X Server has a way of not keeping to standards.  The actual configuration entries are not in /etc/httpd/httpd.conf, but in subdirectories of /etc/apache2/sites. Check out this [FAQ](http://macos-x-server.com/wiki/index.php?title=Apache_ServerAlias).

I would recommend using the Server Admin utility to set up the server.  It will be a lot easier and quicker than trying to get the configuration right manually.  You can always add or change rules later, once the site is up and running.

Comment: Also, I would recommend starting apache2 from there, too, not by running sudo apachectl.  The admin tool remembers your settings and will start services automatically after each restart.

Answer (score 0):

No direct local GUI access possible for a few days, no access via Remote Desktop either. My only way is ssh right now, but I will be happy to try Server Admin utility in a few days. For now I am restricted to the command line. Yes, I edited both /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and /etc/apache2/sites/0000_any_80_.conf, without avail. Is

```
sudo serveradmin fullstatus web
```

anyhow instructive :

```
web:readWriteSettingsVersion = 1
web:totalKBytes = 0
web:emailRulesRunning = no
web:boundToKerberos = yes
web:teamsRunning = yes
web:postfixRunning = no
web:servicePortsRestrictionInfo = _empty_array
web:health = _empty_dictionary
web:currentThroughput = 0
web:passwordResetRunning = no
web:ApacheMode = 2
web:statusMessage = ""
web:apacheVersion = "Unknown"
web:state = "RUNNING"
web:setStateVersion = 1
web:apacheState = "RUNNING"
web:proxyState = "STOPPED"
web:htCacheCleanRunning = no
web:calendarRunning = yes
web:servicePortsAreRestricted = "YES"
web:currentRequestsBy10 = 0
web:logPaths:logPathsArray = _empty_array
web:totalRequests = 0
web:startedTime = ""
```

?

Comment: It seems there is no getting through the firewall, since web:totalRequests = 0.  Are you sure port 80 is open and mapped correctly?

Comment: Good point. I have added "12324 allow tcp from any to any 80 in" to /etc/ipfilter/ipfw.conf but "sudo ipfw show" does not show any of the rules in /etc/ipfilter/ipfw.conf. How do I get those rules considered ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: OK, this seems to be a known bug: other than described in /etc/ipfilter/ipfw.conf rules in this file are NOT considered after reboot. However, additional rules can be implemented via "sudo ipfw add..." from the command-line. Now I have at least access, although file permissions have to be adjusted. Thanks again, greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome, and no problem :)  Be sure to post when you get it running, so others can benefit as well!